# I have a main window with two Content Control and I want to show a single user control across the two

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to create a tiny TicTacToe application in WPF to practice coding.
I created a main window in Xaml with two ContentControl one next to the other, I want to display, while the users play, the game in the main one and the Scoreboard on the side one (they are two adjacent colums of the same grid), those will be handle by 2 different UserControls, this is why the two ContentControls

My login screen is single window and, when i load its user control covers only the ContentControl I load it in, this leaves an awful white strip.
I could create a patch by adding a new user control to be loaded in the empty Content contrel, but I would like to have the login screen to stretch over the two controls as it will look nicer and aI am doing this to learn.

Is there a way to load an user Control across the two User control or to stretch it to cover the empty one?

The Xaml for the main window is:

```
<Window x:Class="TicTacToe_Main_form.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TicTacToe_Main_form"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Tic-Tac-Toe" Height="450" Width="600"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid>
    
    <!--Main page divided in 2 parts to have game on the left and score on the right-->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
    
    
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActionWindow" Grid.Column="0" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="SideWindow" Grid.Column="1" />
    

</Grid>
```

The code behind XAML is

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ActionWindow.Content = new StartNewGame();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance and, if you have any suggestion on how to improve the way I asked the question, I am happy to "listen"

Comment: Add the "stretching" control to the `Grid` and set its `Grid.ColumnSpan` property to `2`? Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

There are several variants, but you don't use MVVM and that's why I'm giving you a variant, but it's not very elegant.

Practically, we make another ContentControl and stretch it on both columns, instantiate the content of this ContentControl and we only play with the visibility.

```
<Grid>
    <!--Main page divided in 2 parts to have game on the left and score on the right-->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Panel.ZIndex="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    x:Name="Logging" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActionWindow"
                    Grid.Column="0" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="SideWindow"
                    Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Below we do the instantiation and then we have both visibility states.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ActionWindow.Content = new StartNewGame();
        // 
        Logging.Content = new Class();
        Logging.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Logging.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```